# MUI DataGrid onCellEditStop returns old value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use an editing API from "@mui/x-data-grid" and simply have editing on the cell and retrieve the new value.

When I use

```
onCellEditStop={(params: GridCellEditStopParams, event: MuiEvent) => {
  console.log(params);
  if (params.reason === GridCellEditStopReasons.cellFocusOut) {
    event.defaultMuiPrevented = true;
  }
}}
```

Console log prints out the old parameters which include the **old value** of the cell instead of the new one to which it was changed.

How do I retrieve a new value after editing the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback that you need is onCellEditCommit:

```
onCellEditCommit={(params: GridCellEditCommitParams, event: MuiEvent) => {
  console.log(params);
  if (params.reason === GridCellEditStopReasons.cellFocusOut) {
    event.defaultMuiPrevented = true;
  }
}}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/datagriddemo-material-demo-forked-i9iz3f?file=/demo.tsx:1661-1677

The property that will have the new value is value, formatted value will show the previous value if available.

Comment: Thanks, parameters of that function is not entirely correct in your code but I managed to make it work with disableSelectionOnClick and onCellEditCommit.

Comment: Yup, good point the type is different, edited

Comment: Careful, onCellEditCommit is outdated and will not work in MUI 6 anymore (**breaking change!**)

https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/editing/#persistence

Comment: With mui 6 can I use onCellEditStop rather than processRowUpdate?
Whit onCellEditCommit there was updated values, with onCellEditStop the params.value is not updated.
My old code is based on onCellEditCommit and I would not change the code.

Answer (score 1):

In the newest version of MUI (MUI 6), you will need to use value setter in GridColumns definition for that purpose (https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/editing/#value-parser-and-value-setter).

```
const gridColumns=[
    {
        field: 'fieldName',
        editable:true,
        valueSetter:(params: GridValueSetterParams)=>{
            let value = params.value; //<-- this contains the new value
            let oldValue = params.row.fieldName;//<-- this contains the old value
            if(value!=oldValue){
                // Do something with the changes
            }
            return params.row
        }
    },...]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with `@mui/x-data-grid v6`:

```js
const handleCellEditStop = (params: GridCellParams, event: MuiEvent) => {
  const { id, field } = params;
  setTimeout(() => {
    params.value = apiRef.current.getCellValue(id, field);
  }, 100)

  console.log('stop', { params });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

@mui/x-data-grid v6: When you're editing cells, you might notice that the `params` object returns the old values from your array. To get the updated cell value, use the following solution instead.

```js
onCellEditStop={(params, event) => {
  const newValue = event.target.value;//here is the new value
}
```

Comment: the event param does not have a target property. I get this error because it's a MuiEvent type

Property 'target' does not exist on type 'MuiEvent'.
  Property 'target' does not exist on type '{ defaultMuiPrevented?: boolean | undefined; }'.ts(2339)